# Browsing sharepoint site using full domain shows blank page?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, permissions

I have a server, when use machine name internally, ie.

```
 http://mySPServer
```

it works fine. however, we want external users to access this site, the external url is

```
 http://mySPServer.myinc.com
```

but it shows a blank page, no matter we browse from internal or external.

I had this issue before, and fixed it. But I could not remember what I did. Anyone has any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have an Alternate Access Mapping for the Web Application with the FQDN in it. Also make sure the IIS Site binding exists for that AAM.

Answer (score 1):

Check that Default Web Site in IIS is not hijacking requests to http://mySPServer.myinc.com, so verify/remove Bindings on that site in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Questions: Is the web app configured for Anonymous access or are the external users on the domain?

- ping the address first and see if the IP address returned is pointing to the correct server (If you do not get a response then you have other issues)
- Ensure you have both address under Alternate access mapping
- Ensure both addresses exist under IIS bindings
- I don't think you need a DNS entry for the FQDN